# Enable TLS 1.1 on NGINX

Tags: nginx, ssl

I need to enable TLS 1.1 on a specific sub-domain until an API client can update their server.

I use NGINX and letsencrypt certbot to manage my security certificates.

I've tried adding the following to my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` within the server block for the specific sub-domain:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
```

I also tried:

```
ssl_ciphers EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!SEED:!DSS:!CAMELLIA;
```

But tls testing sites like `https://www.cdn77.com/tls-test` still say that tls 1.1 is disabled.

How can I enable tls 1.1 for a specific sub-domain?

My (mostly) complete `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file contains the following:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile            on;
  tcp_nopush          on;
  tcp_nodelay         on;
  keepalive_timeout   65;

  proxy_connect_timeout       600;
  proxy_send_timeout          600;
  proxy_read_timeout          600;
  send_timeout                600;

  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  client_max_body_size 500M;

  include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type        application/octet-stream;

  # The file in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d` folder is 100% commented out
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

  index   index.html index.htm;

  server {

    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # The `/etc/nginx/default.d` is empty
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
      # This is a nodejs app using expressjs / angular to host my primary domain site
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }

  }

  server {

    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Conneciton 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
  
  }

  server {

    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  staging.api.domain.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.api.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.api.domain.com/privkey.pem;

    # I commented this out so i can specify my own ssl_protocols and ssl_ciphers for this block
    # include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    # I've also tried the following:
    # ssl_ciphers EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!SEED:!DSS:!CAMELLIA;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Conneciton 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }

  }

}
```